# WebView doesn't load non-standard port in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to load a website on port 8100 using a WebView. It is HTTPS. I don't have control to change the port it's served on.

It loads fine in the simulator and devices on iOS 10. It's failing on an iPad Mini running iOS 9.3.5 - all I see is blank white screen.

I tried adding "App Transport Security Settings > Allow Arbitrary Loads" to YES in Info.plist, but this did not fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to open in safari first on your ipad mini. network is not same.

Comment: I get a certificate warning "Cannot Verify Server Identity" - after hitting "trust" it works in Safari - I'm guessing there's no easy workaround for this besides getting the certificate fixed?

Comment: ios 9.0 and above ATS enforces https connection, you need to get the certificate fixed or try adding domain in your app's Info.plist file ( Not sure if this will block your approval process ).

Answer (score 0):

As you set `Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES` also set following key under `NSAppTransportSecurity`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trust the certificate as you are hitting https://

Write below in your class. It is for debugging purpose do not release this in production.

```
//Swift
extension NSURLRequest {
    static func allowsAnyHTTPSCertificate(forHost host: String) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

//Objc

@implementation NSURLRequest (NSURLRequestWithIgnoreSSL) 

+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```